# Difference between "reach out to" and "reach to"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

> He himself runs a show in the evening wherein his team **reaches** out to dangerous places.

It is written "reaches out" ,so, can I use simply "reaches to" instead of reaches out? Would it be grammatically right?

Comment: Did *you* write that context? If so, please tell us *exactly* what you want it to mean. If not, please provide a link to a more complete context so we can figure it out for ourselves. It looks to me as if **to reach out** here has the sense [to try to communicate with a person or a group of people, usually in order to help or involve them](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reach-out-to-sb), in which case you *can't* discard ***out*** because it's part of the phrasal verb.

Comment: [*reach out*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reach-out-to-sb) is a phrasal verb. You shouldn't break it.

Comment: I'd also add that I think the cited usage is playing a bit "fast and loose" with the phrasal verb. Normally, you "reach out" to ***people*** (who can be communicated with), not (inanimate, "mindless") ***places***, so strictly speaking it should probably be *his team reaches out to **people in** dangerous places*. This wouldn't always matter, but in this specific context, even with the inclusion of ***out*** there's always going to be some confusion regarding the normal sense of ***reach = attain, arrive at, get as far as***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not so much fast and loose with the verb as with the metonymy of "dangerous places".

Comment: @Luke Sawczak: Point taken. Or more precisely, the "slack" relates to the combination of *both* elements. As to the metonymy, I have to admit when I looked at this yesterday, I assumed that those dangerous places were effectively "literal" (I imagined a *news* show, with his team bravely traveling to and reporting from sites of natural disasters, military conflicts, etc., even at some risk to their personal safety. Looking again, I think actually even that's being stretched - it probably refers metaphorically to *exploring socially contentious / sensitive **topics***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, very possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's three possible things going on with *out*, depending on the context:

- *Out* can be tacked on to a lot of verbs of motion to emphasize that the motion is done over a significant distance away from where the subject is currently.

  > I walked out to the park yesterday. (The park is far away)
  >
  > Reach your hands out to the sky. (Your hands will be as far away from you as possible)
- It can also mean performing a verb of motion while exiting a place, such as your home or a city.

  > We left out of Chicago yesterday.
  >
  > I ran out to the store for a minute. (I left home and went to the store, *run* is being used to create a sense of urgency, in that I don't mean to stay at the store long and do a lot of shopping)
- *Reach out to* is a phrasal variation of *reach* that means "to make exploratory contact with an unknown and/or potentially hostile party."  X in *reach out to X* will most likely be a person or place where people are if this meaning is intended.

I would guess the third meaning is likely meant.

*Reaches to* is technically grammatical but it will change the meaning, unless the dangerous place is something like a craggy cliff (dangerous due to terrain and not due to people) and you are in a boat moving towards it, e.g. literally going to a dangerous place and not meeting dangerous people.

*Reach to* typically means to stretch a body part to touch something.  So it will also sound awkward if you change *reach out to* to *reach to* here, unless your show is about a bunch of people in groups that reach down in or around holes or other dangerous places.  (A vessel traveling to a place *reaches* the place but does not typically *reach to* the place.)

Comment: Certainly the third meaning here. "Reaching out to dangerous places" as in "establishing relationships with people who live in dangerous neighbourhoods, probably with a philanthropic or humanitarian intent", I think. :)

Comment: Depending on the context, "his team reaches to dangerous places" might conceivably be an elision of "his team reaches *from safe places* to dangerous places", referring to the extent of the team's expertise or experience.